# How to deploy a static React app

Tags: reactjs

I'm hoping you can point me in the right direction for finding out how to deploy a static single page react app to my server. Nothing fancy, no routing, no database--imagine a simple 'hello world' page. What do I need to do to get the react goodness into static files I can upload to my server?
Thanks!

Comment: There is literally this tutorial on the React website https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill Oh good lord. How did I miss that. Thanks for the virtual head slap :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a great boilerplate to get started. This will deploy to heroku no problem. https://github.com/alanbsmith/react-node-example Also checkout the react docs facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

Basically if using ES6 or JSX you do your build first, then deploy.